# How to show the dropdown blank when one of the option from the otehr dropdown is selected?

Tags: jquery

```
How to show the dropdown Country blank when the State dropdown option is selected and also viceversa(country dropdown is selected and the state dropdown is blank
```

Does we need to include the option blank in the option or else is there any syntax,
 I have done through the disable option,that when i select the dropdown of country the dropdown of state disabled.?
    
    
    jQuery select / dropdown box example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>jQuery select / dropdown box example</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#country").change(function () {


     // disable the dropdown:

if($("#country option:selected").val()=="NONE"){
    $('#state').attr('enabled','true');
}else {
    $('#state').attr('disabled','true');
}


  });

    });
</script>
</head><body>

<select id="country">
<option value="NONE">-- Select --</option>
<option value="China">China</option>
<option value="United State">United State</option>
<option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
</select>
<select id ="state">
<option value ="AP">AP</option>
<option value ="SP">SP</select>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method. Ex:

```
if($("#country option:selected").val()=="NONE"){
    $('#state').removeAttr('disabled');
}else {
    $('#state').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```